# How to remove duplicates results from Custom Record Saved Search in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am creating a saved search on a custom record to show all the records, but when I preview the saved search many duplicate records are being displayed on the screen. How can I eliminate the duplicates?
And I don't want to remove all my Saved Search columns as when i used summary type as Group that time unique results were coming but all columns were not coming.

Comment: In the saved search results, are you joining data from Transactions ?

Comment: Yes in results i'm showing  transactions that is sourcing from custom record's field

Comment: Then unless you need data from the Transaction line (like the Item on each line), you can remove the duplicated lines by filtering on the Transaction Mainline = True

Answer (score 0):

You need to add summary type to the "missing" columns as well.

When you have summary type for some fields, those without summary type will not show on the results by default. You will see them only when you click the link from one of the grouped columns.